# Drawing line in sheet using PHPExcel

Tags: drawing, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to generate Excel spreadsheet using PHP. Generally, this application can address what I need when working with PHP and spreadsheet, however when I try to draw line in the spreadsheet, I cannot find how to do it.
Normally I can do it in Excel application by doing Insert > Shapes and choose the line. But how to do it programatically using PHPExcel?
I need to do it since I have to plot point and connect them to make a straight line from one cell to another cell in spreadsheet (hence I cannot use Chart feature for this purpose).
Many thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Autoshapes aren't supported by PHPExcel, so the option doesn't exist. I think you'd need to use COM (with MS Excel) or PUNO (with Open Office) to do this, because I don't believe any other PHP/Spreadsheet library supports this feature

Comment: Hi @Mark, thanks for your respond. After reviewing both COM and PUNO, I decided not to use both of them. I cannot use COM as my server is Linux and I think I need more time to review & test whether PUNO is stable enough. And I think I will deliver the report in PDF instead, I will loose lots of interaction I can offer to my user, though

Comment: Unfortunately, it will be next year at the earliest before I even get to start work on writing autoshapes for PHPExcel, the codebase is getting a complete rewrite for version 2.0, and it won't be until after that release